# Evitar cierre de modal cuando se hace click fuera de él en bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

¿Cómo evito que al tener una modal de Boostrap abierta y se le de en la parte gris que pone de fondo no se salga de la ventana modal?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Para `bootstrap 3`:**

Desde `html`:

```
<a data-controls-modal="your_div_id" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" href="#">
```

Desde `jQuery`:

```
$('#idDelModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})
```

Otros atributos `data`:

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  backdrop   |  Incluye un elemento modal-backdrop. Como alternativa, |
|             |  especifique `static` para un fondo que no cierre el   |
|             |  modal en clic.                                        |
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------|
|  keyboard   |  Con valor `booleano: true` evita cerra el modal cuando|
|             |  se presiona la tecla `escape`                         |
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------|
|    show     |  Muestra el modal cuando se inicializa                 |
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------|
|   remote    |   deprecado desde v3.3.0. Carga desde una vía remota   |
|             |  el contenido del modal                                |
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------|
```

[Referencia completa](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/)

Answer (score 9):

Como se muestra en [la documentación de Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/), se pueden pasar opciones al momento de crear un diálogo modal.

```
$('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})
```

- **backdrop**: booleano para establecer si se presenta un elemento de fondo. Alternativamente, se puede usar `static` para que aparezca pero no se cierre al hacer click.
- **keyboard**: booleano para establecer si se cierra el modal al presionar <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Comment: Excelente aportación Mariano, gracias

Comment: De esta forma abre la modal al iniciar al dom