# ¿Como evitar cierre de un modal despues de ejecutar el evento de un boton (dentro del modal)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap

tengo un modal de bootstrap el cual contiene un textbox y un teclado numérico dentro, entonces al hacer click a algún botón se debe "escribir" el numero del botón en el textbox. El problema es que al hacer click a cualquier botón (del teclado del modal) el modal se cierra. El numero si se queda escrito pero para verlo debo abrir el modal otra vez. Hay alguna manera de hacer que el modal no se cierre?.

Leí que se puede solucionar colocando un updatepanel dentro del cuerpo del modal para evitar el autopostback.. pero no tengo idea de como.

```html
<!--VENTANA MODAL -->  
<div class="modal fade" id="recep"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header" style="align-content:center">
<h2 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">TITULO MODAL</h2>
</div>
<div class="form-group" >
<div class="modal-body" style="align-content:center;">
        
<h2 style="text-align: justify">Ingrese un numero:</h2>
<!--teclado numerico -->
<asp:Button ID="b0" runat="server" Text="0" OnClick="b0_Click"/>
<asp:Button ID="b1" runat="server" Text="1" OnClick="b1_Click"/>
<asp:... etc...

<!--textbox -->
<asp:textbox id="sem" runat="server" autocomplete="off"></asp:textbox> 
</div>
</div>

<!--cerrar -->
<div class="modal-footer" style="align-content:center">
<asp:Button id="cr" runat="server"  data-dismiss="modal" text="CANCELAR" />

<!--guardar-->
<asp:Button id="RR" runat="server" text="ACEPTAR" OnClick="RR_Click"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
  <!--VENTANA MODAL -->
```

```html
webform aspx.cs
  protected void b0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                sem.Text = sem.Text + "0";
       }
```

Gracias por leer.

Comment: Mira este link [Evitar cierre de modal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39478/evitar-cierre-de-modal-cuando-se-hace-click-fuera-de-%C3%A9l-en-bootstrap)

Comment: hola, gracias por tu respuesta, pero en esa pregunta que me pasaste piden algo diferente a lo que yo necesito, ahi se cierra al dar click fuera del modal. Pero en mi caso se cierra al ejecutar el evento de un boton, y quiero evitar eso

Comment: aaaaa , disculpa veré que puedo hacer.

Comment: tienes que quitarle el `data-dismiss = "modal"` , eso evita el cierre del modal por el boton que indicas

Comment: Hola, el data-dismiss = "modal" lo tengo en un boton llamado cancelar, el cual si es para que se cierra el modal, pero en ninguna otra parte lo puse.

Comment: A ver si te sirve, me imagino que todo debe estar dentro de un form, entonces al form en su propiedad onsubmit tendrías que ponerle return false, osea algo asi:
<form onsubmit="return false">

Comment: ¿Hay algún motivo por el que estás utilizando asp:buttons?¿Necesitas realmente que se ejecuten en servidor?

Comment: @Kiko_L los utilizo para poder hacer estos eventos:  protected void b0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                sem.Text = sem.Text + "0";
       }

Comment: Nose de que otra manera hacerlo si no es con asp:buttons

Comment: Con un simple <input type="button">. El asp:button hace un postback y de ahí que se te cierre el modal (está recargando la página).

Comment: Puedes subir el  código que tiene el evento click de tu botón asp? te ayudaré a ejecutarlo de forma asíncrona con ajax, así podrás ejecutar tu consultas de asp con controles de html y javascript. **Los eventos de servidor requieren recargar la página, y a no ser de que pongas variables de sesión y cargues el modal con respuestas en el evento onload de la página, no podrás hacer lo que buscas.**

Comment: Te dejo un fiddle de cómo sería esa parte sólo con javascript (utilizando jQuery). Luego podrías meter el botón "ACEPTAR" como un asp:textbox si quieres para que se ejecute en servidor (aunque tienes la opción de utilizar Ajax). https://jsfiddle.net/Kiko_L/hyyxt7n2/5/

Comment: Hola @JorgeLuisAlcantara este es el codigo que tienen los botones protected void b0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                sem.Text = sem.Text + "0";
       }

Comment: Seguro que sólo necesitas eso? Porque concatenar un cero al string de un textbox sería tan fácil como hacerlo con dos lineas de javascript

Comment: jaja si es todo lo que necesito, pero yo nose nada de javascript

Comment: hehehe queda entonces, dame un momento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cualquier cosa me avisas, recuerda que los Ids que pones en el servidor cambian a la hora de estar en el navegador.

```
<!--VENTANA MODAL -->
<div class="modal fade" id="recep" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="align-content: center">
                <h2 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">TITULO MODAL</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="modal-body" style="align-content: center;">

                    <h2 style="text-align: justify">Ingrese un numero:</h2>
                    <!--teclado numerico -->
                    <button id="b0" type="button">0</button>
                    <button id="b1" type="button">1</button>

                    <!--textbox -->
                    <asp:TextBox ID="sem" runat="server" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--cerrar -->
            <div class="modal-footer" style="align-content: center">
                <button id="cr" data-dismiss="modal">CANCELAR</button>

                <!--guardar-->
                <asp:Button ID="RR" runat="server" Text="ACEPTAR" OnClick="RR_Click" /> <%--Aquí podrías redireccionar a otra página con un mensaje de confirmación--%>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#recep">
  lanzar modal
</button>
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#b0").on("click", function () {
        $("#head_sem").val($("#head_sem").val() + "0"); 
        // En mi caso el ID es MainContent_sem, sí no funciona inspeciona la página y mira que ID tiene tu textBox
    });
    $("#b1").on("click", function () {
        $("#head_sem").val($("#head_sem").val() + "1");
        // En mi caso el ID es MainContent_sem, sí no funciona inspeciona la página y mira que ID tiene tu textBox
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Jose Luis Alcantara gracias por tu respuesta, lo he probado pero no me ha funcionado :c

Comment: inspeccionaste y viste cual es el id del textbox? tienes referenciado jquery?

Comment: hola, si lo tengo referenciado y si cambie el id del textbox :c

Comment: Qué error te sale?, yo lo probé con mi VS y todo normal

Comment: ninguno, solamente no escribe nada en el textbox

Comment: Inspecciona el navegador y ponte en la pestaña de consola, seguro que ahí sale cual es el error.

Comment: el error que aparece es: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at webform.aspx:138

Comment: y asi aparece mi textbox en el navegador <input name="ctl00$head$sem" type="text" maxlength="2" id="head_sem" minlength="1" autocomplete="off" style="height:56px;width:341px;font-size: 40px; border: 2px solid  dodgerblue; 
border-radius: 4px; margin:20px; outline: none; box-sizing: border-box; transition: .3s; text-align:center">

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75149/discussion-between-jorge-luis-alcantara-and-sunflower).